# TFS get build agent working folder programmatically

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the working folder of a build agent (through TFS REST API)?

I'd like to clean this folder during the reboot of the build agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't the REST API to retrieve the working folder of a build agent.

The working folder is defined when your deploy the build agent. Commonly it should be like this **D:\VSOAgent_work** (the location which you deployed the agent to).

To clean the folder during the reboot of the build agent, you just need to create a **.cmd/.bat** file to delete the **_work** directory, and copy it into the **start up** folder in Windows Explorer.

Please note that you need to **run the cmd/bat with administrator**.

**Delete command sample:**  (Just change the **dir** accordingly, the command will delete all the files and sub-folders, but not delete the directory _work)

```
@ECHO OFF

Set dir=D:\VSOAgent\_work\

Echo Deleting all files from %dir%
del %dir%\* /F /Q

Echo Deleting all folders from %dir%
for /d %%p in (%dir%\*) Do rd /Q /S "%%p"
@echo Folder deleted.


exit
```

**To find the Startup folder:**

For your user account : Win + R run `shell:startup`
For all users Win + R run  `shell:common startup`

For how to auto start Programs as Administrator, you can reference this article:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/autostart-programs-windows-10-make

Comment: Nice. We just found 40 gig on one of our machines. Hard to believe the devs never thought about cleaning up after the agents.